# Convert from update on change to update on save

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner, how to convert from update on change to update on save, now function `onUpdateNote` (located in `App.js`) updates text (inside `<input>` below `<p>Title</p>` and `<textarea>` below `<p>Description</p>` in `Main.js`) on change, need text in the fields to be updated when saving when press `<button>Save</button>` (located `Main.js`).

How it looks in the browser:

[image: screenshot]

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [activeNote, setActiveNote] = useState(false);

  const onAddNote = () => {
    const newNote = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: "Untitled Note",
      body: "",
    };
    setNotes([newNote, ...notes]);
  };

  const onUpdateNote = (updatedNote) => {
    const updatedNotesArray = notes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === activeNote) {
        return updatedNote;
      }
      return note;
    });
    setNotes(updatedNotesArray);
  };

  const onDeleteNote = (noteId) => {
    setNotes(notes.filter((note) => note.id !== noteId));
  };

  const getActiveNote = () => {
    return notes.find((note) => note.id === activeNote);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-border">
        <Sidebar
          notes={notes}
          onAddNote={onAddNote}
          activeNote={activeNote}
          setActiveNote={setActiveNote}
        />
        <Main
          onDeleteNote={onDeleteNote}
          activeNote={getActiveNote()}
          onUpdateNote={onUpdateNote}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import bin from "../images/bin.png";
import magnifier from "../images/magnifier.png";

const Main = ({ onDeleteNote, activeNote, onUpdateNote }) => {
  const onEditField = (key, value) => {
    onUpdateNote({
      ...activeNote,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  if (!activeNote)
    return (
      <div className="app-main">
        <div className="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by title"
            className="search-input"
          />
          <img src={magnifier} alt="search" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />
        </div>

        <div className="no-active-note">No Active Note</div>
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <div className="app-main">
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by title"
          className="search-input"
        />
        <img src={magnifier} alt="search" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />
      </div>
      <div className="app-main-note-edit">
        <div className="main-title-block">
          <p>Title</p>
          <img
            src={bin}
            alt="Delete"
            height={50}
            width={41}
            onClick={() => onDeleteNote(activeNote.id)}
            style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
          />
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          placeholder="Note title"
          value={activeNote.title}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("title", e.target.value)}
          autoFocus
        />
        <p>Description</p>
        <textarea
          id="body"
          placeholder="Write your note here..."
          value={activeNote.body}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("body", e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="app-buttons">
          <button onClick={""} className="button-new-save">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add state for the note currently being edited into `Main.js`. Then when the button is clicked (and only then) call `onUpdateNote` with the state of `Main.js`

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import bin from "../images/bin.png";
import magnifier from "../images/magnifier.png";

const Main = ({ onDeleteNote, activeNote, onUpdateNote }) => {
  const [editingNote, setEditingNote] = useState(activeNote); // initial state is the active note passed as props
  const onEditField = (key, value) => {
    setEditingNote({
      ...editingNote,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };
  
  // if the activeNote reference in the props is changed, update the current state to reflect that.
  useEffect(()=>{
    setEditingNote({...activeNote});
  }, [activeNote]);

  if (!activeNote)
    return (
      <div className="app-main">
        <div className="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by title"
            className="search-input"
          />
          <img src={magnifier} alt="search" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />
        </div>

        <div className="no-active-note">No Active Note</div>
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <div className="app-main">
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by title"
          className="search-input"
        />
        <img src={magnifier} alt="search" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} />
      </div>
      <div className="app-main-note-edit">
        <div className="main-title-block">
          <p>Title</p>
          <img
            src={bin}
            alt="Delete"
            height={50}
            width={41}
            onClick={() => onDeleteNote(activeNote.id)}
            style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
          />
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          placeholder="Note title"
          value={editingNote.title}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("title", e.target.value)}
          autoFocus
        />
        <p>Description</p>
        <textarea
          id="body"
          placeholder="Write your note here..."
          value={editingNote.body}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("body", e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="app-buttons">
          <button onClick={()=>onUpdateNote({...editingNote})} className="button-new-save">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: It gives an error(src\components\Main.js
  Line 5:41:  'useState' is not defined   no-undef     
  Line 14:3:  'useEffect' is not defined  no-undef ), needs to add something to App.js

Comment: you need to import `useState` and `useEffect`, I've updated my answer.

Comment: again error ( Line 17:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'activeNote'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setEditingNote' needs the current value of 'activeNote', you can also switch to useReducer instead of useState and read 'activeNote' in the reducer)

Comment: Either disable this error or add `activeNote` to the dependency array: `useEffect(()=>..., [activeNote.id, activeNote])`

Comment: another error,  from browser(TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')...src/components/Main.js:17)

Comment: That is in fact a bug. Remove the `activeNote.id` from the dependency array. Also please stop suggesting useless edits to my post.